# Reading Markdown text from asset and loading it in Markdown() widget

Tags: flutter

I am trying to read a markdown file from assets folder and able to show the content in my widget as below:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          child: FutureBuilder(
              future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/data/text.md'),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Text(snapshot.data ?? '', softWrap: true);
              }
            ),
          ),
        )
      );
  }
```

With this, I am able to display the text. But, I would like to wrap this content inside Flutter's `Markdown` widget. How should I do that? `Markdown` has only data, which accepts string and not another widget.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Should be the same just `Text(...)` replaced by `Markdown(...)`, wouldn't it?

Comment: This should work,

`Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Title'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Card(
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          child: FutureBuilder(
              future: DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString('assets/data/text.md'),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                return Markdown(data: snapshot.data);
              }
            ),
          ),
        )
      );
  }`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, Thanks. I was focussing on adding a new widget by wrapping FutureBuilder. Totally, forgot the way text is returned in the builder function.

Comment: Thank you for your various remarks, but it is not too practical when the text is very long.